# SSRS report column list sort order

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reporting, ssrs-2012

Hi for my ssrs report i am using a matrix to display data row as a two column list and
I am using the following expression in order to group the row;

> =ceiling(rownumber(nothing) / 2) 
>   and

the following expression to group column;

> =ceiling(rownumber(nothing) mod 2)

similar to https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/12331/Simple-way-to-show-multi-column-data-in-SSRS-Horizontally-or-Vertically.html

it is working correctly however i would like results to be display alphabetical order going vertical instead of horizontal.

Like.

```
Record a    Record d

Record b    Record e

Record c    Record f
```

Instead of

```
Record a    Record b

Record c    Record d

Record e    Record f
```

i have order by in my sql query

any suggestions on how to achieve this?

Comment: Have you tried switching the expressions of row and column?

Comment: You can use a multi-column layout. Go to the report properties and set the columns=2. This will give you a up-down/left-right type output as long as your width remains  like -->Number of Columns * Column Width < Page Width. It works for most cases. Grouping and page spillover may cause grief, however.

Comment: Have tried switching them over they just display as two rows and multiple columns instead. @Anand

Comment: @RossBush trying to avoid the two column layout it causes so many issues for such a simple report. such as when previewing the report it displays in just one column

Comment: Any ideas guys ?

Comment: Have you tried modifying your stored procedure or query to return the data this way?

Comment: I only have order by in sql query. Do you know any sql query functions that may solve this ?

Comment: @RossBush Could you clarify in which report properties window you are seeing the option for setting number of columns?

Comment: @ mohsensajjadi - The property can be set in the object inspector when the body of the report is selected. You can pull the report down so that no controls are on top and click the report white space then look on the properties window and you should see a Columns property.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify your sql for this. The hack below could be used if you do not want to use multiple columns.

```
DECLARE @T TABLE
(
    TableID INT,
    Value1 NVARCHAR(20),
    ShouldBe INT
)

    INSERT INTO @T (TableID,Value1,ShouldBe)
    VALUES 
    (1,'A',1),
    (2,'B',3),
    (3,'C',5),
    (4,'D',2),
    (5,'E',4),
    (6,'F',6),

    (7,'A',1),
    (8,'B',3),
    (9,'C',5),
    (10,'D',2),
    (11,'E',4),
    (12,'F',6),

    (13,'A',1)



    DECLARE @NumberOfRowsPerPage INT = 3
    DECLARE @NumberOfColumns INT = 2

    SELECT PageNumber,Value1
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ColumnOrder=ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY PageNumber,ColumnTile  ORDER BY TableID),*
        FROM
        (
            SELECT ColumnTile=NTILE(@NumberOfColumns) OVER(PARTITION BY PageNumber ORDER BY TableID),*
            FROM
            (
                SELECT PageNumber=( (DataRowNumber -1) / (@NumberOfRowsPerPage * @NumberOfColumns )) + 1, *
                FROM
                (
                    SELECT DataRowNumber=ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY TableID) ,*
                    FROM @T
                )AS A
            )AS B
        )AS C
    )AS D
    ORDER BY
        PageNumber,ColumnOrder,DataRowNumber
```

The query will produce the following output based on the RowsPerPage and NumberOfColumns.

```
Page   Value
1   A
1   D
1   B
1   E
1   C
1   F
2   A
2   D
2   B
2   E
2   C
2   F
3   A
```